# Creating a log with VBS

Tags: logging, vbscript

I currently have the following script copying a certain folder to every computer in computers.txt. Though it skips computers that are turned off obviously, but I would like to know which computers have been skipped or at least which computers succeeded.

```
InputFile = "c:\scripts\input\computers.Txt"
Const OverWriteFiles = True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
Do While Not (objFile.AtEndOfStream)
strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
On Error Resume Next
objFSO.CopyFolder "\\baardrob\Software\PACS Beheer Tools\PACS Beheer Tools" , "\\" & strComputer & "\c$\PACS Beheer Tools\Pacs starten" , OverWriteFiles
Err.Clear
Loop

MsgBox "Done"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
Set myLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\my.log", 2)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
  On Error Resume Next
  objFSO.CopyFolder ...
  If Err Then myLog.WriteLine strComputer & vbTab & Err.Number & vbTab _
    & Err.Description
  On Error Goto 0
Loop
myLog.Close
```